# About activemq network of brokers, what's the difference between multicast discovery and fixed list of URIs?

Tags: activemq-classic

http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html

I'm trying activemq network of brokers, following above article.
It works all fine with  a fixed list of URIs.
But I have some problem with the multicast discovery. That is, the network bridge between two activemqs on the same machine can be started. But the bridge cannot establish between different machines(I tried telnet, it is ok).

I don't know which part went wrong. So I want to ask that is these two kind of network just difference in configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet is proving that Unicast networking is working, multicast may requires additional configuration in your network.

Are those machines in the same subnet?
Is there a router or Layer 3 switch between them? (it would then requires to be configured if the answer is yes..)

You could use iperf to test the multicast connectivity, you can look at [Generating multicast traffic article](http://taosecurity.blogspot.com/2006/09/generating-multicast-traffic.html) to know how to do that.